# Building mod_php5 For Ubuntu Apache2

Tags: server, software-installation, apache2, php

I need to install mod_php5 for Apache 2.4 under Ubuntu in my homelab, in order to test an upgrade to an application whose installed version will not run under PHP>5 and whose current version will not run under PHP<7.

Because PHP5 is no longer supported, I have compiled it from source, using a bare `./configure` command (followed, of course, by `make` and `sudo make install`). I have successfully installed the PHP5 cli, but have been unable to install mod_php5. When I run `a2enmod php5` and then `apache2ctl restart`, I get a message which boils down to `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and Apache fails to start. The command `find ./php-5.5.9 -name libphp5.so -print` comes up empty, so evidently the .so is not being generated by `make`.

What do I need to do to build mod_php5 so it can be installed and enabled under Ubuntu's version of Apache 2.4?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is no longer supported here, but you can install PHP 5.6 on an 18.04, 20.04, 21.10, or 22.04 system with [Ondřej Surý's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/). This will save you a whole lot of pain going forward ...

Comment: Use the PPA and save yourself time. Otherwise, your problem is caused by not finding the PHP installation files on which mod_php5 depends. Build PHP 5 first.

Comment: @matigo That would actually qualify as an answer in my opinion. I'll try it and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, building an Apache module requires `apxs` (the APache eXtenSion tool), which is not installed by default. I needed to install the package `apache-dev` as well.